# Creating graph using networkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to make a graph for this [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gHCHs1719sZOC2eZ5mShPtUMbnwfFDCFaM9gWxLRaOQ/edit?usp=sharing) using the following code:

```py
import networkx as nx
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.Graph()
filename = "tubedata.csv"

with open(filename) as tube_data:
    starting_station = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(tube_data, delimiter=',')]

with open(filename) as tube_data:
    ending_station = [row[1] for row in csv.reader(tube_data, delimiter=',')]
    
with open(filename) as tube_data:
    average_time_taken = [row[3] for row in csv.reader(tube_data, delimiter=',')]
    
with open(filename) as tube_data:
    for line in tube_data:
        graph.add_edge(starting_station, ending_station, weight=average_time_taken)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_101/53822893.py in <module>
     17 with open(filename) as tube_data:
     18     for line in tube_data:
---> 19         graph.add_edge(starting_station, ending_station, weight=average_time_taken)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py in add_edge(self, u_of_edge, v_of_edge, **attr)
    870         u, v = u_of_edge, v_of_edge
    871         # add nodes
--> 872         if u not in self._node:
    873             self._adj[u] = self.adjlist_inner_dict_factory()
    874             self._node[u] = self.node_attr_dict_factory()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I have searched the error and understand that I need to pass a data structure that is immutable. I changed the code to the following:

```py
with open(filename) as tube_data:
   starting_station = (row[0] for row in csv.reader(tube_data, delimiter=','))

with open(filename) as tube_data:
   ending_station = (row[1] for row in csv.reader(tube_data, delimiter=','))
   
with open(filename) as tube_data:
   average_time_taken = (row[3] for row in csv.reader(tube_data, delimiter=','))
   
with open(filename) as tube_data:
   for line in tube_data:
       graph.add_edge(starting_station, ending_station, weight=average_time_taken)
```

This resolves the above error but produces a graph with only two nodes and 1 edge? How can I capture the full data as a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the graph using the following steps:

1. Use the `pandas` library to read in the data into a DataFrame object
2. Create an edge list [(source, target, weight)] from the data frame rows
3. Create an empty directed graph in networkX
4. Add edges to the DiGraph object by passing in the edge list

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('tubedata.csv',header=None)

edgelist = data.apply(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[3]),axis=1).to_list()

# edgelist
# [('Harrow & Wealdstone', 'Kenton', 3),
#  ('Kenton', 'South Kenton', 2),
#  ('South Kenton', 'North Wembley', 2),
#  ('North Wembley', 'Wembley Central', 2),...

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edgelist)

list(G.edges(data=True))[:5]
# >>>[('Harrow & Wealdstone', 'Kenton', {'weight': 3}),
#     ('Kenton', 'South Kenton', {'weight': 2}),
#     ('South Kenton', 'North Wembley', {'weight': 2}),
#     ('North Wembley', 'Wembley Central', {'weight': 2}),
#     ('Wembley Central', 'Stonebridge Park', {'weight': 3})]
```

You can also get the same result going straight for `from_pandas_edgelist` [see documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html), after renaming the pandas data frame columns:

```
data = data.rename(columns={0:'source',1:'target',3:'average_time_taken'})

G2 = nx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='source', target='target', edge_attr='average_time_taken', create_using=nx.DiGraph)


list(G2.edges(data=True))[:5]
# [('Harrow & Wealdstone', 'Kenton', {'average_time_taken': 3}),
# ('Kenton', 'South Kenton', {'average_time_taken': 2}),
# ('South Kenton', 'North Wembley', {'average_time_taken': 2}),
# ('North Wembley', 'Wembley Central', {'average_time_taken': 2}),
# ('Wembley Central', 'Stonebridge Park', {'average_time_taken': 3})]
```